# phpword 0.18.2 integration with phpstan

Tags: phpword, phpstan

There are `phpstan` configuration files in the `phpword` sources https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/0.18.2 , but `composer` does not include these on `phpword` installation, thus there are none of these in the vendor directory.

[[screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9pK0.png)

Any alternative solutions are also welcome.

The root cause is phpstan warning:

```
 Class PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\MPDF referenced with incorrect case: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\Mpdf.
```

Runs on: PHP 8.0, laravel 8, phpstan 1.10.25, phpword 0.18.2

Thanks

Comment: The `phpstan.neon` file in the PHPWord repository is for PHPWord itself being analysed by PHPStan. It's not relevant to you if you're a user of PHPWord. You're not supposed to include that file in your project that uses PHPWord.

Answer (score 0):

The `phpstan.neon` file in the PHPWord repository is for PHPWord itself being analysed by PHPStan. It's not relevant to you if you're a user of PHPWord. You're not supposed to include that file in your project that uses PHPWord.

The error reported by PHPStan is correct:

> Class PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\MPDF referenced with incorrect case: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\Mpdf.

The class is called `MPDF`, not `Mpdf`: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/0.18.2/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/MPDF.php

So in order to fix the error reported by PHPStan, you need to reference the class by its correct name in your source code: `MPDF`

Although class names in PHP are case-insensitive, PHPStan chooses to report this as a problem, because historically, there might be problems with certain autoloaders and running PHP applications on file systems with different case sensitivity, like Windows vs. Linux.

So under certain circumstances, `Mpdf` class might be found on Windows, because `MPDF.php` is the same as `Mpdf.php` and the class will load, but the same application might not run on Linux, because `Mpdf.php` and `MPDF.php` aren't the same file.

Comment: But it runs perfectly fine in a container based on Linux image

Comment: Whats more, it is PhpOffice class that gets reported by PhpStan, not the application one

Comment: This is the the problem line : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/aca10785cf68dc95d7f6fac4fe854979fef3f8db/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/MPDF.php#L50

Comment: In that case send a PR to PHPWord that fixes that PHPDoc :) Problem solved.